# position: fixed won't keep the elements fixed to the bottom of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the following styles:

```
#fullpage-menu > .gradient {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.3rem;
}
```

where `#fullpage-menu` has the styling:

```
#fullpage-menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--secondary-button-color);
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    animation: expand-fullpage-menu 500ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.07, 1.43);
    z-index: 1001;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    padding: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(-100%);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and

```
.apply-for-org .apply-button {
    background-color: var(--dark-secondary-button-color);
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 10rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--title-color);
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    user-select: none;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: bahnschrift;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Where `.gradient` is displayed on the bottom of each fullscreen menu, and `.apply-button` is displayed at the bottom of the `.apply-for-org` `<div>`, which also has the id `#fullpage-menu`.

In other words, the `.apply-for-org` menu should have a gradient bar at the bottom, which should stay there when scrolling through the div if the content height exceeds the screen height.

In addition, the HTML would look like this for a fullpage-menu:

```
<div id="fullpage-menu" class="apply-for-org">
  
  <!--Content and other cool stuff-->

  <button class="apply-button">Apply for Organisation</button>
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

So why does this not work? Why doesn't the gradient bar and the apply button stick to the bottom of the screen when scrolling through the content?

[image: Before resizing to make the div scrollable]

[image: After resizing, the elements won't stick when scrolling]

EDIT 15/04/2021:

```css
#fullpage-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #121a21;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#fullpage-menu > button.close {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  font-family: bahnschrift;
  background-color: #070b0e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

#fullpage-menu .gradient {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  background: rgb(131,58,180);
  background: linear-gradient(41deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(181,73,227,1) 28%, rgba(253,29,29,1)     83%,   rgba(252,145,69,1) 100%);
}

.apply-for-org .apply-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: #070b0e;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-family: bahnschrift;
  cursor: pointer;
}




/*Styling exclusive for this example*/

#example-content {
  height: 100rem;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,187,233,1) 100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullpage-menu" class="apply-for-org">
<button class="close">Close</button>


<div id="example-content"></div>




<button class="apply-button">Apply for Organisation</button>
<div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

I also noticed that it works just fine in the code snippet that I posted, but apparently it doesn't work as well on my locally hosted server..

If it matters, I'm using .ejs instead of .html, but it shouldn't be of any importance (i believe)

Comment: `position: fixed;` moves an element out of the flow and relative to the viewport (screen). If you want to place it relative to an element, you have to use: `position: absolute;` and give the parent `position:relative;`

Comment: Can you please post more HTML and CSS to create a minimal version of what you have? Currently there is not enough information for us to help you with a solution.

Comment: Sure, I'll do it as soon as possible, but I'm going to check out what tacoshy had to say first :)

Comment: @tacoshy, I've tried it, but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: @disinfor I have updated the question with a complete example. I could however not reproduce the problem

Comment: A fixed element can be positioned against its parent, if you set a `transform` property on the parent. Try adding `transform: translate(0,0)` to the parent element.

Comment: @disinfor I fixed the problem, but I wouldn't doubt that this also works. I can add it to my answer below :) Thanks for the help, either way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem in the distant or near future, it can be fixed by wrapping all the content in another div with `position:block` attribute:

```
<div id="fullpage-menu" class="apply-for-org">
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <!--Place all the fancy content here-->

    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <button class="apply-button">Apply for Organisation</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then by giving these styles, everything will work :)

```
#fullpage-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #121a21;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


#fullpage-menu .gradient {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  background: rgb(131,58,180);
  background: linear-gradient(41deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(181,73,227,1) 28%, rgba(253,29,29,1)     83%,   rgba(252,145,69,1) 100%);
}

.apply-for-org .apply-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: #070b0e;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-family: bahnschrift;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*This part is important!*/
.apply-for-org > .main-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I don't know why, apparently my CSS and HTML knowledge is too limited, or I am too stupid, but at least this works. It wouldn't work without the `.main-wrapper` element wrapping all of the content.

*EDIT:*
`disinfor` mentioned something that might just as well work, haven't tried it though:

> A fixed element can be positioned against its parent, if you set a transform property on the parent. Try adding `transform: translate(0,0)` to the parent element.